# How to only use created_at in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want only use created_at , how to do it?

I know:

This can custom timestamps name

```
const CREATED_AT = 'created';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated';
```

This can disable timestamps

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Eloquent does not provide such functionality out of the box, but you can create it on your own using the `creating` event callback:

```php
class User extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->created_at = $model->freshTimestamp();
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this one is the best way to hack through the Eloquent model timestamps. It works for me on Laravel 5.1.

Comment: Pretty work! And `parent::boot();` should be called first.

Comment: This is an excellent answer for a single model. For a decoupled and reusable solution, I created an Observer based on this approach. Thanks! With observer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42822380/2188595

Comment: can improve this to use `$model->setCreatedAt($model->freshTimestamp());` which will use the `static::CREATED_AT` const

Comment: In 5.4, the problem it gives is that it also doesn't populate in updated_at field even after update (Eloquent update).

Comment: just use `const UPDATED_AT = null;` at the top of your model class like said in below answers!

Comment: You can also skip the boot code by just doing `$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();` in your migration

Comment: With this approach you will compete with built in functionality. I think it is better to use what is there. Learn what we have before building on it.

Comment: I use the above approve but found an additional conditional check was helpful in allowing me to set an alternate created_at on the model when created it.

        ```static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (! $model->isDirty(static::CREATED_AT)) {
                $model->created_at = $model->freshTimestamp();
            }
        });```

Answer (score 71):

Use on the top:

```
const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

And for 'created_at' field, you can use:

```
const CREATED_AT = null;
```

**UPDATE FOR LARAVEL 5.5.0 - 5.5.5**

This was broken [in Laravel 5.5.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20901) (and fixed again [in 5.5.5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21178)).

If you are using 5.5.x, make sure you are on the newest version.

If for some reason you cannot be on the newest version, here is a workaround.

Set the public $timestamps to false:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

And when necessary:

```
public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value) { 
    $this->attributes['created_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); 
}
```

OR

```
public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value) { 
    $this->attributes['updated_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); 
}
```

When the two fields "created_at" and "updated_at" are required, you do not have to do anything, of course ;)

Comment: Can someone please explain this? What does it do exactly?

Comment: I agree with Anthony – this needs more explanation.

Comment: `const UPDATED_AT = null;` stops Laravel trying to update the updated_at field within a table.

Comment: I agree with @hackel, this is not advisable at all

Comment: @hackel is wrong for Laravel 5.8 the source code explicitly says `if (! is_null(static::UPDATED_AT) &&` well, he/she was right about using source, but he/she was not politically correct calling people names.

Answer (score 36):

I have a better answer from [**here**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10005) for [Laravel 5.2 or above](https://laravel.com/).

U can use this in model-

```
class User extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false; // disable all behavior
    public $timestamps = true; // enable all behavior
    public $timestamps = [ "created_at" ]; // enable only to created_at
    public $timestamps = [ "updated_at" ]; // enable only to updated_at
    public $timestamps = [ "created_at", "updated_at" ]; // same as true, enable all behavior
}
```

So, for your question, the answer is -

```
public $timestamps = [ "created_at" ]; // enable only to created_at
```

### Re-

```
public $timestamps = [ "created_at" ];
```

Not working in Laravel 6+

Comment: It is for Laravel 5.2 or +

Comment: Don't use this answers without studying the vendor code yourself. This does not work because it is still a proposal and has not been implemented yet(right now 5.3).

Comment: Hi, I am using it and it is working just fine for me

Comment: I don't think this is working at all. It was suggested by the user in the post not implemented by laravel.

Comment: I am using it in Laravel 5.2 in my current project and working fine for me :)

Comment: A pull request was created for this but it was never merged. The recommended solution is in [issue #19139](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19139#issuecomment-300698303) and in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700805/533242)

Comment: public $timestamps = [ "created_at" ];

still doesn't work in Laravel 5.5.13.

Comment: Not working in Laravel 5.8, it gives me an error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' `

Comment: **public $timestamps = [ "created_at" ];** not working in laravel 6

Comment: public $timestamps = [ "created_at" ]; not working in laravel 8.9.0 :/

Answer (score 21):

My solution:

```
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration {

   public function up() {

      Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table){

         $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
   });
}
```

This works for me

Comment: are there any downsides to this?

Comment: Your PHP script could be working with a different timezone than your database.

Comment: I see a Big downside that you cannot emulate a date change in your unit-tests, you know like `Carbon::setTestNow($now);`

Comment: but if you really need it, better use `$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();`

Comment: @minitauros it's always better to use unified timezone, such as UTC everywhere in your application without timezones, and then just shift the timezone for the user on the frontend depending on their needs

Answer (score 11):

**Since Laravel 5.***

Model:

```
//  Disable updated_at (only created_at)
class Book extends Model
{
     const UPDATED_AT = null;

     /* ... */
}
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table): void {
    /* ... */
    $table->timestampTz('created_at')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: This is the proper way to accomplish this in 2020. The accepted answer is no longer needed.

Comment: Definitely the best solution.

Comment: If this the proper way to accomplish this in 2022 (and indeed it is also in 2022). then this should be the accepted answer.
People might just waste time or worse, dirty their project with unnecessary code because they were looking at the old (wrong) answer

Answer (score 5):

I solved by adding default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in my database for the column `created_at`. And In my model I use this below code

```
public $timestamps = false;
protected $dates = ['created_at'];
```

I hope this method works in all versions of laravel.

Comment: Note that your database time may differ to apache/php time.

Answer (score 4):

On your `model` set

`const UPDATED_AT = null;`

or

`const CREATED_AT = null;`

it stops Laravel trying to update the updated_at/created_at field

It works for Laravel 5.8

And it is better than overwrite: `setUpdatedAt` in your `model`

```
public function setUpdatedAt($value) : self 
{
    // Do nothing.
    return $this;
}
```

because it is shorter and because the check for `if (! is_null(static::UPDATED_AT)` is happening in source code earlier than triggering 
`setUpdatedAt`

Answer (score 3):

To disable only updated_at, you can override Model::setUpdatedAt() method, like following :

```
public function setUpdatedAt($value) {
    // Do nothing.
}
```

Of course, if you wanted to do this for the created_at column, it's just as easy. And that's work for Laravel 5.1

Comment: I found that it does not work for 5.1.7 because it updates timestamp also in Builder update calling `return Arr::add($values, $column, $this->model->freshTimestampString());`

Comment: I think it's `function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value)` CMIIW

Comment: And it works for Laravel 5.8, but I prefer `const UPDATED_AT = null;`

Answer (score 3):

Use on the top the class:

`const UPDATED_AT = null;`

or

`const CREATED_AT = null;`

Comment: voted up, it is a correct answer but too little details. Next time, please mention a Laravel version of yours.

Comment: duplicate answer

Answer (score 2):

In version 5.3 I just did `public $timestamps = false;` and then added protected $fillable = ['created_at']. Note: You can add anything you want, just make sure it matches the one in your table.`

Comment: does not work in laravel 5.8, you better don't do it if you don't what to change it during Laravel upgrades.

Comment: By doing this you telling the model that a http request can manually edit the created_at field. This in not a good solution. Don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this is using a new `__construct` method.

See:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
            parent::__construct($attributes);

            $this->attributes['created_at'] = $this->freshTimestamp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach with only `setUpdatedAt` did not work with Laravel 5.1.7 because it has one more place where `updated_at` gets processed.

Model class performUpdate method calls Builder class method:

```
public function update(array $values)
{
    return $this->query->update($this->addUpdatedAtColumn($values));
}
```

which leads us to

```
return Arr::add($values, $column, $this->model->freshTimestampString());
```

I'm not sure, why Laravel is processing updated_at twice - in `performUpdate` with `$this->updateTimestamps()` and then later in Builder with `$this->addUpdatedAtColumn($values)`.

With some debugging, I found that you have to also update your model with getUpdatedAtColumn override. At first I was afraid that it will try to update a non-existent field "null", but it turned out that `Arr::add` is smart enough to ignore null keys.

**So, in your model class add these:**

```
public function setUpdatedAt($value)
{
    // Do nothing.
}

public function getUpdatedAtColumn()
{
    return null;
}
```

This should be enough to disable both updates.

Comment: The getDates() method should also be overridden so it does not include `null`:

`public function getDates()
    {
        $defaults = [static::CREATED_AT];

        return $this->timestamps ? array_merge($this->dates, $defaults) : $this->dates;
    }
`

Comment: This is also going to screw up updating relations because of all the calls to getUpdatedAtColumn from relationship classes.

Comment: Could you give an example of that @hackel ?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel **5.7**, this was enough for me to have it work:

In migration:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
```

instead of classic `$table->timestamp('created_at');`

In model:

```
const UPDATED_AT = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is simple, decoupled, and reusable is to use a Model Observer. The idea is to capture the `creating` event and fill the `created_at` attribute. This method may be used by any number of models without having to repeat code or using unofficial tricks. Most importantly, it closely resembles the internal mechanics of the Model class, thus avoiding unexpected errors.

1) Create `SetCreatedAt` observer in `App\Observers`:

```
namespace App\Observers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SetCreatedAt
{
    /**
     * Sets created_at when creating the model.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function creating(Model $model)
    {
        $model->setCreatedAt($model->freshTimestamp());
    }
}
```

2) On `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` inside the `boot` method add the following line for each of the models that you want the `created_at` to be generated for:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    // Replace OrderLog with your model
    OrderLog::observe(SetCreatedAt::class);
}
```

3) On your models, the only thing that you have to do is disable the timestamps:

```
// Disable timestamps on the model
public $timestamps = false;
```

Tested with Laravel 5.3, but it should work with previous versions as well.

Good luck!

Comment: what is OrderLog? is that your model name?

Comment: if I need multiple models to have this should I replicate the observe in the boot with each one?

Comment: @ClearBoth Yes, OrderLog is just an example; replace it with your Model. To use in multiple models, just duplicate the `YourModel::observe(SetCreatedAt::class)` line for each of your models. I wrote a more detailed tutorial here https://arianacosta.com/php/laravel/setting-created_at-timestamp-laravel/

Comment: I have implement this, however, are you sure this is the wise option to do so? I have several models in the app service provider, that mean it will be loaded on every page request and that could affect the performance.

Comment: @ClearBoth That's a good point. The performance impact of registering the observer should be almost non-existent. However, if you find that in your application you are loading dozens of models on the AppServiceProvider, then maybe it would be a good idea to move that to its own service provider and load them selectively. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

In 5.4, the problem it gives is that it also doesn't populate updated_at field even after update (Eloquent update).

instead add this method

```
public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    // auto disable update_at in inserts 
}
```

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev please take a look on the question date, laravel 5.8 doesn't even exists yet.

Comment: You are right. Maybe it was a valued answer back in the day and you did great putting a Laravel version into it. But if someone picked this answer they would need to review their code during laravel upgrade procedure, which should be mentioned. I cannot verify the answer so I'm not voting here.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone here looking for having `updated_at` and not `created_at`, but none of the other answers seems to work for you:

In Laravel 8, you need to set the model property `CREATED_AT` to `null` and the `UPDATED_AT` to 'updated_at' or any other name you want to your updated_at  field.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The name of the "created at" column.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    const CREATED_AT = null;

    /**
     * The name of the "updated at" column.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';


    public function setCreatedAt($value)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

And your migration...

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
    $table->timestamp('updated_at'); // instead of $table->timestamps();
});
```

I am not sure why you need to set this property inside your model since it is already set in the parent class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, but it only worked for me after I made this change.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default value for `created` field in your MySQL table and set

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

in your model.

Comment: I suppose so. For example, in your migration you'd write: $table->timestamp('failed_at')->useCurrent(); (Laravel uses this in the failed_jobs migration stub).

Answer (score -3):

I used very simple hack ;)

class MyClass extends Model {

```
const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
const UPDATED_AT = 'creation_date';
```

}

I just pointed both to the same column :)

Comment: Uh, ,this will cause the create_at column to be overwritten every time the model is saved.  Do NOT do this!  (It would work if you only wanted the updated_at column, however.)