# Custom created_at and use only custom created_at

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel.

I want to add timestamp for all insert actions in Laravel using custom field name such as `ct` and not using `updated_at`.

I came up with below, but without luck. All of my tables have `ct` field with `not null` property.

```
class ProductLog extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'ct';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->created_at = $model->freshTimestamp(); => 1)
            $model->setCreatedAt($model->freshTimestamp()); => 2)
        });
    }
}
```

Both of 1) and 2) still throws me an error saying 'ct' doesn't have a default value.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you have `ct` in the migration files ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to only use created\_at in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886497/how-to-only-use-created-at-in-laravel)

Comment: @Maraboc No, I do not. Do I have to have that in migration file in order to use `static::creating`?

Comment: it depends on what you want you said _I want to add timestamp for all insert actions_ what do you mean add it to database or what ?

Comment: @Maraboc Sorry that I was not clear. I want to automatically insert a value ,current time, to `ct` field of tables when I insert certain row to the table.

Comment: So in this case you have to add it to the migration file ! and do it like this `$model->ct = $model->freshTimestamp();`

Comment: @Maraboc ok. So only when I add `ct` field using migration file, it would work. And if I created `ct` field manually using SQL script, it would not work. Did I understand it correctly? Is there any other way not to use migration and still achieve what I want?

Comment: @smchae you can use `const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';` from respective model and add `$timestamp false;`

Comment: @smchae check my answer. I've just tested it and it works perfectly without any additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested this and it works perfectly:

```
const UPDATED_AT = null;
const CREATED_AT = 'ct';
```

There's no need to do anything else. With this solution, Laravel will use `ct` as `created_at` and will not add `updated_at` to any update queries.

Comment: This answer does not work. It would give me an error saying ct does not have a default value, which means there is no value inserted for ct field. I am also using `protected $table = 'Table name'`. Will this affect the behavior?

Comment: @smchae try to remove all other code (listener, `timestamps = false` etc). It worked for me in a clean model.

Comment: It only works with `(new SomeModel)->save()`, not with query builder (e.g. `(new SomeModel)->insertGetId($data)`. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @smchae that's because `insertGetId` is not an Eloquent method. Use `create`, it will use Eloquent and will return inserted object so you will be able to get it's ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ProductLog extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'ct';

    public function setUpdatedAt($value)
    {
        return $this;
        // this method does nothing now
    }
}
```

Eloquent will set the `created_at` (`ct`) field for you on insert [as it does already when `$timestamps = true;`] and wont be able to set the `update_at` field now.

You can see what Eloquent is doing in the code `Model@performInsert` and `Model@performUpdate`.

Comment: this is an alternate unneeded solution ... there is no need to override `setUpdateAt` as Alexey has pointed out, `updateTimestamps` checks to see if that const is null or not

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class ProductLog extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'ct';
    const UPDATED_AT = null;

    public $timestamps = false;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->ct = $model->freshTimestamp();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: it would give me an error saying `ct` does not have a default value, which means there is no value inserted for `ct` field

Comment: still the same. It does not work and returns the same error