# Laravel pivot table timestamps

Tags: laravel, timestamp, pivot

I have a small question about Laravel's pivot table and it's timestamps (created_at/updated_at).

The scenario is:

> assign many tickets to many users, and see **when** it was assigned.

I want to keep the `created_at` timestamp, but want to get rid of the `updated_at` column when creating the migration.

In my research I've stumbled upon the solution to declare `public $timestamps = false;` in the model. But a pivot table does not have a model - and it will disable both `created_at`and `updated_at`.

Other than this I haven't found any results that matches my case.

Can anyone enlighten me here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But a pivot table does not have a model

This is not true. From the Laravel docs:

> If you would like to define a custom model to represent the
>   intermediate table of your relationship, you may call the `using` method
>   when defining the relationship. Custom many-to-many pivot models
>   should extend the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` class
>   while custom polymorphic many-to-many pivot models should extend the
>   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot` class.

To do this, just create a model for your pivot table and then the rest of the steps are pretty much the same as they would be for a usual model.

You can set `const UPDATED_AT = null;` to only use `created_at`. More details in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638865/7377984)

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

From Laravel 5 you can just fix this issue and maintain your time stamps in your pivot table using `withTimestamps()` like that.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many