# how to show only last record with query builder in laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I only want to display the latest data from the tanggal_ins that I have marked, how to?

This is my json data:
[image]

And this is my query:

```
$cuti = DB::table('t_cuti as cuti')
        ->join('m_karyawan as kary', 'kary.nik', '=', 'cuti.nik')
        ->join('m_rumah_sakit as rs', 'rs.kd_rs', '=', 'kary.kd_rs')
        ->join('m_unit as unit', 'unit.kd_unit', '=', 'kary.kd_unit')
        ->join('m_jabatan as jab', 'jab.kd_jabatan', '=', 'kary.kd_jabatan')
        ->leftJoin('t_cuti_adjust as adj', function ($leftJoin) {
            $leftJoin->on('adj.nik', '=', 'cuti.nik')
                ->latest();
        })
        ->select('adj.tanggal_ins','cuti.saldo_cuti','kary.nik','kary.nm_karyawan','rs.nm_rs','unit.nm_unit','jab.nm_jabatan')
        ->whereYear('adj.tanggal_ins', '<', $year)
        ->orWhere('adj.tanggal_ins', null)
        ->get();
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Have you tried the limiting options described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)?  I suggest reading the docs, they are the best place to start.

Comment: i already change tanggal_ins to created_at, and only enabled created_at like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29886522/12128603. but keep doesn't worked

Comment: I have tried using groupBy, but the value of created_at not display: https://pastebin.com/r33V7ELk you can see this result on this link https://pasteboard.co/IKQhujS.png i need more help from you, thanks..

Comment: i think the problem in left join, cause i already tried limit in laravel ->take(1) inside left join but doesnt worked. and, when i tried outside leftjoin its worked for limit

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are trying to do. Your question title says `show only last record`, and the text says `display the latest data`.  OK, that is pretty clear.  To do that in a DB query you would first **sort** your results, and then **limit** the number you retrieve. For eg `ORDER BY created_at`, and `LIMIT 2`. In Laravel query builder that would be for eg `orderBy()` and `limit()` (I linked to the docs already). But your query has no ordering, and no limiting ...

Comment: the above problem has been resolved, I use the basic select from laravel and combined with the select function from postgreSQL, thanks for your response and attention.

Answer (score 1):

Use [orderBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

```
->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

This will make descending order by ID.
->orderBy('id', 'desc')

and use [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) instead of get().

Comment: the above problem has been resolved, I use the basic select from laravel and combined with the select function from postgreSQL, thanks for your response.