# new Model fills updated_at

Tags: lumen

I am using Lumen and I just found an issue. When creating a new model, the code also fills 'updated_at' despite the model is new and it wasn't updated yet (since it was just created). Since this is a crucial flaw and would be strange that it wasn't noticed till now, I presume I am doing something wrong.

App\User.php:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'date_created';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'date_updated';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'role_id',
        'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'token',
        'password',
        'date_password_reset',
        'token_password_reset'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'date_created' => 'datetime:Uv',
        'date_updated' => 'datetime:Uv',
        'date_password_reset' => 'datetime:Uv'
    ];

    protected $with = ['userRoles'];

    protected $validationRules = [...];
}
```

App\Http\Controllers\UsersController.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Exception;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    ...

    // first attempt
    public function create(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, (new User)->rules('create'));

        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        $user->role_id = $request->input('role_id');
        $user->active = $request->boolean('active');
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(
            [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'User successfully created',
                'data' => User::query()->find($user->id)
            ], 200);
    }

    // second attempt
    public function create(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, (new User)->rules('create'));

        $user = new User;
        $user->update($request->input());
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        $user->active = $request->boolean('active');
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(
            [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'User successfully created',
                'data' => User::query()->find($user->id)
            ], 200);
    }

    // third attempt
    public function create(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, (new User)->rules('create'));

        $user = new User($request->input());
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        $user->active = $request->boolean('active');
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(
            [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'User successfully created',
                'data' => User::query()->find($user->id)
            ], 200);
    }
}
```

DB migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    protected $initialUsers = [
        [
            'name' => 'Administrator',
            'email' => 'admin@localhost.local',
            'password' => null,
            'role_id' => null,
            'active' => 1
        ]
    ];

    protected $initialRoles = [
        [
            'name' => 'Administrator'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'User'
        ]
    ];

    protected $initialUserRoles = [];

    public function up()
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();;

        Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->timestamp('date_created')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('date_updated')->nullable()->default(DB::raw('NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        });

        foreach ($this->initialRoles as $data) {
            DB::table('user_roles')->insert($data);
        }

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('token', 255)->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('active');
            $table->timestamp('date_password_reset')->nullable();
            $table->string('token_password_reset')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('date_created')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('date_updated')->nullable()->default(DB::raw('NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('users_roles')->onDelete('set null')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

        $password = Hash::make('xxx@x');
        $role_id = DB::table('users_roles')->where('name', 'Administrator')->value('id');
        foreach ($this->initialUsers as $data) {
            $data['password'] = $password;
            $data['role_id'] = $role_id;
            $user_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($data);

            $this->initialUserRoles[] = [
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'role_id' => $role_id
            ];
        }

        DB::commit();
    }
}
```

Query created by Eloquent:

```
array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `role_id`, `active`, `date_updated`, `date_created`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' (length=131)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=7)
          0 => string 'Test User 5' (length=11)
          1 => string 'test6@test.net' (length=14)
          2 => string '$2y$10$lvRGKuznotd8lqwCj2diIONGjyiAkhaNthWGjQyFWbBqiyuf20wpG' (length=60)
          3 => string '1' (length=1)
          4 => boolean true
          5 => string '2020-06-17 10:30:07' (length=19)
          6 => string '2020-06-17 10:30:07' (length=19)
      'time' => float 5.5
```

All three `create()` attempts are filling up 'updated_at' despite that one should stay NULL until an actual update is done on this model. Can you guys give me any indication what am I doing wrong? Would also like to keep the `$model->update($request->input())` functionality if possible, so that I do not need too assign each field manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to only use created\_at in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886497/how-to-only-use-created-at-in-laravel)

Comment: Not really, but it have me some pointers on how to continue. Also got a second opinion but didn't like it, so I will post my solution that I like.

Answer (score 0):

Because Lumen/Laravel is handling the "created_at" and "updated_at" fields on it's own and it sets both to the same timestamp when a record is created (which I do not like), I created my own solution.

First is already in place when creating a migration. I created my own timestamp fields and those are already properly updated by MySQL:

```
$table->timestamp('date_created')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('date_updated')->nullable()->default(DB::raw('NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

And of course, disable timestamp handling for Lumen in `User.php` model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

But in case that this is not possible for any reason or if you want Lumen/Laravel to handle those, this is the code I wrote in `User.php` model:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'date_created';
const UPDATED_AT = 'date_updated';

public $timestamps = false;

public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->{self::CREATED_AT} = $model->freshTimestamp();
    });
    static::updating(function ($model) {
        $model->{self::UPDATED_AT} = $model->freshTimestamp();
    });
}
```